# Opening/Closing incoming traffic on ports for application

Tags: c++

I am looking for some info on how to close / open ports for incoming traffic only.
I would like to add this as a extra security measure for my C++ project, so data can still be sent to my server but not received when the function gets triggered and vice versa.

I tried googling but only linux & python results show up.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. Please expand.

Comment: do you mean you want to close ports opened by other applications on the server?

Comment: Im basicly just trying to block incoming traffic on a port only for the process of my application as a extra security measure as my application needs incoming traffic to function properly.
So if there is any unauthorized use of my application i want to block the ports incoming traffic so it cant function.

Comment: Please clarify "port".  Also update you post with your OS since the standard C++ language has no concept of ports.

Comment: Are you talking about device drivers?  Some OSes don't support device drivers; others have a lot of attributes (such as read-only or write-only).